# Values not working - if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, webforms

I'm currently working on a program to calculate values and I can't seem to get my if statement to work.

What I want the if statement to do is:

Get the values from the form.

if the values in ddlLamination are 0 (which means No Lam) then I want the total to show up as $0.00 but if the SelectedHeight and SelectedWidth have a value of 0 show $0.00 also but if there is anything above 0 in ddlLamination and SelectedHeight and Selected Width then Make the LaminationSetupCharge = $20.00.

If anyone could help me figure out why all i'm getting back is $0.00 even when I have values that should make it show $20.00 that would be great. Thanks.

```
 Double SelectedHeight = Convert.ToDouble(txtLabelHeight.Text);
 Double SelectedWidth = Convert.ToDouble(txtLabelWidth.Text);

if (ddlLamination.SelectedValue == "0") 
{
    LaminationSetupCharge = 0.00;
}
else if (SelectedHeight > 0)
{
    LaminationSetupCharge = 0.00;
}
else if (SelectedWidth > 0)
{
    LaminationSetupCharge = 0.00;
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(ddlLamination.SelectedValue) > 0)
{
    //Lamination Setup Charge.
    LaminationSetupCharge = 20.00;
}
```

Comment: I see no indication here that you've confirmed that the actual values of the variables at runtime really are what you assume they are. When you put a breakpoint on the first `if` and examine everything in the watch window, what do you see? When you step through the code with F10, hovering the mouse over every expression to examine its value, what do you see?

Comment: ^ Set up a breakpoint, debug, and see what the `ddlLamination.SelectedValue` actually is.

Comment: You say ` if the SelectedHeight and SelectedWidth have a value of 0 ` but you _coded_ ` if the SelectedHeight **OR** SelectedWidth have a value of 0 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood you correctly your condition should be only this:

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(ddlLamination.SelectedValue) > 0  && SelectedWidth > 0 && SelectedHeight > 0)
{
    //Lamination Setup Charge.
    LaminationSetupCharge = 20.00;
}
else {
    LaminationSetupCharge = 0.00;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have been at this all day. Thanks for the help. Very appreciated. :)